# Determine the general solution for $2\cos^2x-5\cos x+2=0$

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Determine the general solution for $ 2\cos^{2}x-5\cos x+2=0$

My attempt:

$2u^2 - 5u + 2 = 0$

$(2u - 1)(u - 2) = 0$

$u = \frac{1}{2}$ or $u = 2$

$\cos(x) = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\cos(x) = 2$

The answers on the worksheet are as follows but my answer does not match...

A. $2.89$, $3.39$

B. $3.39$, $6.03$

C. $0.25$, $6.03$

D. $4.46$, $6.03$

Comment: the answers appear incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right set of answers? Your "general solution" should be in the form $x_0\pm2\pi n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Also notice that cos(x)=2 is impossible.

Comment: @user73122: Are you sure you wrote the problem correctly?

Comment: your solution seems correct.check once given option

Comment: Did you check if your answer should be in radian or degree ?

Comment: The complete set of real solutions is $\pi/3+2\pi k, 5\pi/3+2\pi k,\; k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

[\begin{array}{l}
\\
\\
{\rm{                }}2{\cos ^2}x - 5\cos x + 2 = 0\\
2\cos x(\cos x - 2) - 1(\cos x - 2) = 0\\
{\rm{               }}(2\cos x - 1)(cosx - 2) = 0\\
2\cos x - 1 = 0{\rm{   OR    }}\cos x - 2 = 0\\
\\
{\rm{Case 1}}\\
2\cos x - 1 = 0\\
{\rm{       }}\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\\
{\rm{      }}\cos x{\rm{ }} = \cos \frac{\pi }{3}\\
{\rm{         }}\therefore x  =  2n\pi  \pm \frac{\pi }{3}{\rm{      }}\left( {n \in Z} \right)\\
\\
{\rm{Case2}}\\
\cos x - 2 = 0\\
{\rm{       }}\cos x = 2\\
{\rm{but }}\\
{\rm{       cosx}} \ne 2\\
{\rm{because    - 1}} \le {\rm{cosx}} \le {\rm{1 }}\\
\therefore {\rm{   }}In{\rm{ }}this{\rm{ }}case{\rm{ }},there{\rm{ }}is{\rm{ }}no{\rm{ }}solution{\rm{ }}for{\rm{ }}\cos x{\rm{  }}
\end{array}]

Comment: Your post would look better if you did not bundle everything into one big formula. Having some text helps the readers.

Comment: Use `\cos x` instead of `\rm{cos} x` and use `\mbox{..}` for text within math (if needed).